# React Navigation is not a function?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm using React Navigation. I'm directing you to the conversation after the record insert page. I provide automatic renewal when I redirect. I'm sending a parameter. But that doesn't work. I don't know where I'm making a mistake.

I get this error.

> Uncaught typeerror. TypeError: s.handleRefresh is not a function. (In 's.handleRefresh()', 's.handleRefresh' is undefined

**LeadDetail.js Page**

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params = {} } = navigation.state;        
        return {
            title: 'Müşteri Adayı Detay',
            headerRight: (
                <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreateMeeting', { parentId: params.id, parentType: 'Lead' })} style={{marginRight: 12 }}>
                    <Icon
                        name="calendar-check-o"
                        size={25}
                        color="white"
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            )
        };
    };
```

**CreateMeeting.js Page**

```
    dataSuccess(response) {
        this.setState({ buttonLoading: false });

        Alert.alert(
            'Tebrikler!',
            'Meeting başarılı bir şekilde kayıt edildi',
            [
                { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Meeting', { refreshMeeting: true }) }
            ]
        );
    }
```

**Meeting.js Page**

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params } = navigation.state;
        let refresh = navigation.getParam('refreshMeeting', false);

        if(refresh) {            
            params.handleRefresh();
        }
        return {
            title: 'Görüşmeler',
            headerRight: (
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={navigation.getParam('setOverlay')}>
                        <Icon
                            name="filter"
                            size={25}
                            color="white"
                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>

                    <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={navigation.getParam('setModalVisible')} style={{ marginRight: 12, marginLeft: 20 }}>
                        <Icon
                            name="plus"
                            size={25}
                            color="white"
                        />
                    </TouchableHighlight>                    
                </View>
            )
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the param `handleRefresh`? Instead of `params.handleRefresh();` shouldn't it be `params.refresh();`?
Also, `s.handleRefresh` where is this in your code? I think there is a typo or something like that and I'm considering that `s.handleRefresh` is actually `params.handleRefresh`

**Please edit your question if none of this is correct.**

I don't know where you are setting the param `handleRefresh`, but if you are setting it (please check that and add the code where you do that), maybe here is the reason why this happens.

If you look at the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) they have a not

> React Navigation doesn't guarantee that your screen component will be mounted before the header. Because the increaseCount param is set in componentDidMount, we may not have it available to us in navigationOptions. This usually will not be a problem because onPress for Button and Touchable components will do nothing if the callback is null. If you have your own custom component here, you should make sure it behaves as expected with null for its press handler prop.

This means that the header can render before the component calls `setParams` and that doens't load you params in the first time. What you need to do some checking to avoid that time when the header renders first.

```
//            added some checking 
if(refresh && params && params.handleRefresh) {            
    params.handleRefresh();
}
```

Comment: Works on another page. I did not understand. I'm gonna quit this job and have a waitress.

Comment: @Dodiş Please add the code where you use ` s.handleRefresh` or edit your question

Comment: I searched all code pages. There's no code. params.handleRefresh detects the partition as 's.handleRefresh'.

Comment: @Dodiş Please answer my asked question. `Are you setting the param handleRefresh? Instead of params.handleRefresh(); shouldn't it be params.refresh();?`. And also, have you tried do the checkings?

Comment: Like I said, this code works on the other page. Anyway thanks gave up :)